# Can't display selected row's data from database in javaFX

Tags: java, sqlite, authentication, javafx

---

I am trying to make a user login & registration application in JavaFX & Sqlite.
I am success to Insert data into database on Registration Window and also Select data from database in Login window. 
But i need to show the user's all data (which record at database) in a new window . I had type some code for it, but every time after login it show only the last data on database in user window.

> login code:

```
@FXML
public Label errMesage;

@FXML
public TextField userNameTF;

@FXML
public TextField passwordTF;

@FXML
public Button loginBtn;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public void handleSecoundaryRegestrationLink(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{

    Parent switchAlterRegestrationPage = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/gui/gui1.fxml"));
    Scene sceneAlterRegestrationPage = new Scene(switchAlterRegestrationPage);

    Stage stageAlterRegestrationPage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    stageAlterRegestrationPage.hide();
    stageAlterRegestrationPage.setScene(sceneAlterRegestrationPage);
    stageAlterRegestrationPage.show();

}


public void handleLoginBtn(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
    Parent login = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/gui/user.fxml"));
    Scene sceneLogin = new Scene(login);
    Stage stageLogin = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    if(isValidLoginCOndition()){
        stageLogin.hide();
        stageLogin.setScene(sceneLogin);
        stageLogin.show();


    }
    else{
        errMesage.setText("UserName or Password not Matched!");
    }

}


public boolean isValidLoginCOndition() {

    boolean let_in = false;
    System.out.println("SELECT * FROM user WHERE usrName = "+"'" + userNameTF.getText() +"'"
            + "AND PASSWORD "+ "'" + passwordTF.getText()+"'");
    Connection c = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:regestration.db");
        c.setAutoCommit(false);

        System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
        stmt = c.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM user WHERE USERNAME= " + "'" + userNameTF.getText() + "'" 
        + " AND PASSWORD= " + "'" + passwordTF.getText() + "'");

        while ( rs.next() ) {
             if (rs.getString("USERNAME") != null && rs.getString("PASSWORD") != null) { 
                 String  username = rs.getString("USERNAME");
                 System.out.println( "USERNAME = " + username );
                 String password = rs.getString("PASSWORD");
                 System.out.println("PASSWORD = " + password);
                 let_in = true;
             }  
        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        c.close();
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Operation done successfully");
        return let_in;
}
}
```

> user Form code:

```
@FXML
public Label loginFullName;

@FXML
public Label emailLB;

@FXML
public Label loginFullName2;

@FXML
public AnchorPane usrAP;



@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

}


public void handleShowDetails(){    




    Connection c = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    try {
      Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
      c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:regestration.db");
      c.setAutoCommit(false);
      System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

      stmt = c.createStatement();

      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM user");

      while ( rs.next()) {
         String fullname = rs.getString("FULLNAME");
         String  email = rs.getString("EMAIL");

         loginFullName.setText(fullname);
         emailLB.setText(email);
         loginFullName2.setText(fullname);

         System.out.println( "FULLNAME = " + fullname );
         System.out.println( "EMAIL = " + email );
         System.out.println();

      }
      rs.close();
      stmt.close();
      c.close();
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
      System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
     System.exit(0);
    }

}








public void handleLogOut(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
    Parent logout = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/gui/login.fxml"));
    Scene sceneLogOut = new Scene(logout);

    Stage stageLogOut = (Stage) ((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    stageLogOut.hide();
    stageLogOut.setScene(sceneLogOut);
    stageLogOut.show();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your wanted behaviour right you want to show the user details in a extra Form by calling handleShowDetails function. 
If so the sql call

```
Select * from user
```

will get all users from the database. Then you loop over the data and set a label login fullname which will always show only the last item of the while loop.

So if you only want to show the data of the current logged in user you have to pass these extra parameters to your sql call like

```
Select * from user where usrName=...
```

as you did in your login form.

To optimize you should better store the user data in the login process in an User object to avoid multiple calls on db which you could use during the session.